# No SharePoint 2010 logging

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I've setup a new dev-machine for SP2010. But for some strange reason, I don't get any logging. I already set the diagnostic logging to verbose and disabled flood protection (in some desperate action), but still my logfiles remain nearly empty.

The only entries are from the changing of the logging settings itself.

The actuall problem is, that I have a webpart with some errors, that gives me a nice correlation-id, but I can't find any further details on the error, since my logfiles are empty.

Any hints/suggestions?

Comment: @kyle-trauberman: is that right? I only know about the 14-hive. Is there any other location for logfiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to add the appool account to a group, performance log users, or some variant.

Comment: @anita-boerboom: is that group new to sp2010? I don't recall such a group in moss2007. And I also don't see such a group in my environment.

Looking at the filesystem I noticed, that the WSS_WPG Group has write permission to the logfiles, so that's all right.

Comment: AD group. Guess it will also work when the apppool account is member of administrators. Not writing to ULS log has everything to do with permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The ULS logs are located in the 14 hive:

```
C:\Program Files\Common files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Logs
```

Open the most recent file in this directory and search for the correlation token guid.

Alternatively, you can try the ULS log viewer:

http://ulsviewer.codeplex.com/

Comment: @kyle-trauberman I know that alright - that's how I know that only certain events are written to the logfile. But why aren't **all** events written to the logfile?